How to configure SendEmail Task in Azure Devops YAML pipeline with csv file and address related queries
I need to use that CSV file in the below send email task correctly.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvo.SendEmailTask&targetId=ca4e4e67-3099-4c62-9ea9-bef80e0cc70a&utm_source=vstsproduct&utm_medium=ExtHubManageList
I have the following questions:

First I want to test with personal gmail id, will it work?

What are all mandatory inputs to be filled in the above send email task?

Does it work for distribution group mail id?

What should I give in the from address section below if it is an office mail id in the TO section and if it is a personal gmail id in the TO section?



